# What is the difference between $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a non-empty set. For instance, let it be a set of vectors of the form $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $\mathcal{X}=\{\mathbf{x}_i\mid\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^n,\:i=1,\ldots,m,\:m\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

What is the difference in ***requiring*** that $\mathcal{X}$ is a) a subset ($\subseteq$), and b) a proper (or strict) subset ($\subset$) of $\mathbb{R}^n$? That is, what is the difference between the following expressions
$$
\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Apologies in case the question is too vague, or the answer is too obvious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only distinction to be drawn is whether $\mathcal{X}$ is allowed to equal $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If we really want to make it clear to the Reader this is *not* allowed (a proper subset, as you said), the notation $\mathcal{X} \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ might be better.

In the case described in the top paragraph, the condition seems to be imposed that $\mathcal{X}$ is countable, and in that circumstance it would be impossible for equality to exist (between a countable and an uncountable set).  Then the notational distinction would be moot.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, your edit answered my question!

Comment: Many authors use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ analogously to $<$ and $\leq$, which I think is the best convention. In that case, $\subset$ unambiguously excludes equality and makes a symbol such as $\subsetneq$ redundant. But it's true that the meaning of $\subsetneq$ is clear regardless of the context.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, yes, yes. The analogy is so obvious that I can't even begin to understand why would anyone use $\subset$ to mean both proper and improper containment. (I do understand though, analysts... It's in their blood to 'mangle' notations).

Comment: @GitGud Isn't it obvious? It is very rare to have the need to exclude equality. So one takes the most convenient notation for the common case.